# Why iterator vector::insert is not valid after filling: iterator insert (const_iterator position, size_type n, const value_type& val);

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

> Because vectors use an array as their underlying storage, inserting
>   elements in positions other than the vector end causes the container
>   to relocate all the elements that were after position to their new
>   positions.
>   < http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/ >

I thought that this is the reason that iterator `it` becomes no longer valid after the last line in code below:

```
  std::vector<int> myvector (3,100);
  std::vector<int>::iterator it;

  it = myvector.begin();
  it = myvector.insert ( it , 200 );

  myvector.insert (it,2,300);
```

But if I change the `it`'s definition into `myvector.end();`, it's still the same. What is the reason behind this? How exactly does it work and are there situations where `iterator insert` can be still valid after filling part of vector with some elements? (or single one)

Comment: Oh cplusplus... I find the statement "vectors use an array" incredibly misleading, and totally in line with 90% of terrible "I'm implementing my own vector" code. I might possibly see why someone who's confused would say this, but it's just so misleading...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well yes, that is a reason for iterators **to elements** after (and at, because insertion is done before the given element) the insertion point are invalidated. If you insert to the end, then there are no elements whose iterators could be invalidated. The end iterator is always invalidated, no matter where you insert. The more relevant description on that page:

> **Iterator validity**
>
> If a reallocation happens, all iterators, pointers and references related to the container are invalidated.
> Otherwise, only those pointing to position and beyond are invalidated, with all iterators, pointers and references to elements before position guaranteed to keep referring to the same elements they were referring to before the call.

Here's what `it` points to if you change the first assignment to end.

```
it = myvector.end();
```

`it` points to end, good.

```
it = myvector.insert ( it , 200 );
```

Inserting to end does not invalidate any pointers to elements, but it does invalidate the end iterator which is the old value for `it`. Luckily, you now assign to the iterator returned by insert. That iterator does not point to the end of the vector but to the newly inserted element.

```
myvector.insert (it,2,300);
```

Now `it` is invalidated again, but you don't reassign it, so it remains so.

Of course, then there is the possibility, after each insert, that the vector was reallocated in which case all previous iterators to any part of the vector would be invalidated. That can be avoided by guaranteeing sufficient space with `vector::reserve` before initializing the iterators. The new iterator returned by insert will always be valid, even if the vector was reallocated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better reference and explanation.

> Causes reallocation if the new size() is greater than the old capacity(). If the new size() is greater than capacity(), all iterators and references are invalidated. Otherwise, only the iterators and references before the insertion point remain valid. The past-the-end iterator is also invalidated.

— http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert

In the case where you use `end()`, `size()` still goes above `capacity()`. Try setting the capacity to something larger before `insert()`.

Comment: Now I have vector with `capacity()` "much bigger" than `size()`, but now inserting in place of iterator that could be invalidated works once. When I try to do it once again (and again..) in debug mode, it throws error: **vector insert iterator outside range**, but when I choose to continue, it inserts elements in the begin of vector anyway. In Release mode there are no errors and just inserts elements how I want. Iterator seems valid to me, can someone look into this? I'll give print-screen because of comments lacking ability of formatting text: http://postimg.org/image/82h3lbma7/full/

Comment: I thought that maybe this is because I try to access 'before' the first element, so after  `myvector.insert (it,1,300);` I put `it = myvector.begin()+1;`, but it still throws errors, so I think it's not the case. Any ideas?

Comment: One word about the image above: first error appears in the place the yellow arrow is (next step that will be made) and (if you "try again") in every next line, despite that iterator `it` points to the element that is first (or second, third etc. if we modify it after some insertions) element of vector. After looking more into in, I think iterator goes (?) out of range: even though it points to the correct element, it points to the wrong address? For example, in vector we have: `_Mylast=0x0069b2d8 {200}`, while iterator `it` is: `[ptr] 0x0069b2d4 {200}`

Comment: @Kusavil: As described by my answer, `it` is invalid on the marked line. It was invalidated on the previous line. Passing the invalid iterator to insert has undefined behaviour. In debug mode, the implementation does checks and reports an error. If you continue anyway, you invoke the UB. The only *apparent* effect besides the error is what you wanted. The same thing happens in release (sans the error). Something else *might* happen on another compiler, cpu, etc.

Comment: Now I looked deeper into situation from print-screen and it's not the same. Thanks. I will try to learn in which cases iterators are invalidated, because it can be really confusing sometimes if you don't know something, but things "looks" OK, while the code is wrong.